# drawRect and setNeedsDisplay never be called

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I added a uiview (holderview that carry uimageview ) as subview and asign gesture to it  using

imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
    [imageview setImage:cppobject->OutputImage];
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

```
[holderView addSubview:imageview];
holderView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit ;

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[pinchRecognizer release];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
[rotationRecognizer release];

panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
holderView.tag=101;
[self.view addSubview:holderView];
[holderView sizeToFit];
[self AddInformation];
[holderView retain];
[self retain];
```

then in panRecognizer function (move) I want to draw line using

```
         UIPanGestureRecognizer *gR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender ; 


        NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: [gR locationInView:gR.view]]; 





        [Points addObject:value];


        [holderView setNeedsDisplay];

        NSLog(@"End of measuring") ;
```

and I will use the points in Points to draw line above all the subviews in

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Entered Draw In Rect");

```
if (Measuring) {

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *pathToDraw = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; 

    for (int n = 1; n < [Points count] - 1 ; n++) { 

    NSValue * value = [Points objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)n];

        CGPoint  point = [value CGPointValue]; 

        [pathToDraw moveToPoint:point];


        value = [Points objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)n+1];

        point = [value CGPointValue];

        [pathToDraw addLineToPoint:point];



    }



    [pathToDraw stroke];







}
```

}

the problem is  [holderView setNeedsDisplay]; never call or fire drawRect any suggestion or help regarding that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subclass UIView and implement drawRect in the subclass.

Then when creating *holderview*, make sure you're instantiating your subclassed UIView and not the default UIView.